# Magento 2 : Getting an error "syntax error, unexpected 'Abstract' (T_ABSTRACT)"

Tags: magento2, overrides, fatal-error

I have create 2 files as below :

Namespace/Module/Model/Test.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model;
use Namespace\Module\Model\Payment\Method\Abstract;

class Test extends Abstract
{
}
?>
```

Namespace/Module/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Payment\Method;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;


abstract class Abstract extends DataObject implements \Namespace\Module\Model\Payment\Method\Interface
{
}
```

Now when file "Test.php" is called that time I am getting below error :

> s:221:"Fatal Error: 'syntax error, unexpected 'Abstract' (T_ABSTRACT), expecting identifier (T_STRING)' in '/var/www/html/m2/app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/Payment/Method/Test.php' on line 3";

Does any one have an idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you try changing `extends Abstract` with `extends \Namespace\Module\Model\Payment\Method\Abstract` ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Yes I first try with that but getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Abstract class name

**Because it is reserved keyword in php**

You cannot use any of the [words](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) as constants, class names, function or method names

Comment: But I am using that same thing in Magento 1 and in that I am not getting any issue.

Comment: Change class name it will work.

Comment: It is working.But can you explain that why it is working in M1 and creating an issue in M2 ?

Comment: It is not working with abstract keyword may be check there spell is different than abstract.

Comment: I checked that and spell is "abstract" . :(

Comment: In magento1 class names were namespace_module_model_abstract, so abstract was in combination with different words. But in magento2 class names are \Namespace\Module\Model\Abstract so in this case abstract is treated as a unique word.